# PaymentConfiguration is not recognized in android studio java

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am building an Android app in Java and i want to integrate Stripe payments. I configured the Stripe account and added android dependecies like

> implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.25.4'

When I want to use PaymentsConfigure class, it is not recognized at all and I've tried with so many dependencies, upgraded or downgraded.

The import is never recognized.

```
import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration
```

Also, with this dependency "implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.25.4'" i have this error : "Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'"

Did someone uncountered this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

For the "Can't determine type for tag" error, see https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/6250

- i.e. make sure you you are using the latest version of everything in your environment, Material/Gradle/Android Studio/Android Gradle plugin.

For the general import error, note that it's called `com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration` with capital P and C(the case matters).

Comment: compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
minSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 30
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
Android Studio 4.1

Answer (score -1):

I think you're a bit confused.

There's two components to a Stripe integration, the frontend and the backend.

The frontend is your HTML page or your Android app where the customer enters details. If it's an Android app, you use the [stripe-android](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/) library in your app for that.

The backend is your server on the cloud or so on, that processes payments and updates databases and tracks orders/accounts etc. If your backend server is using Java for business logic, you can use the [stripe-java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/) library to interact with the backend Stripe API.

So it doesn't make sense to use stripe-java in an Android project, as your question implies you're doing.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android

Comment: What I'm saying is that my frontend is in Android and I'm having troubles configuring it!

Comment: Your question says you are importing "stripe-java"(the backend library) into your Android app, and then trying to reference a package that is in "com.stripe.android" (the stripe-android library). They are entirely separate libraries so that's why you get an error like that, it would be expected. I was just trying to explain the confusion to you.

Comment: I have this implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.25.4' too and it is still not working

Comment: Also, with this dependency i have this error : "Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'"

Comment: You should definitely remove stripe-java anyway from the app.